# SQL Server get table name in database trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to use the database level DDL trigger for logging actions in my DB.
I need to get table name and action (insert, update, delete) and write it in table with logs.

Can I get table name in database level trigger and use it to insert table name?
Or need to put triggers on all the tables?

Comment: You say DDL trigger but then give three DML actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a setup that I use on many of my databases.  It demonstrates most of the things that you asked about:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Meta].[DdlEvents](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [sysname] NULL,
    [CreateBy2] [sysname] NULL,
    [SchemaName] [sysname] NULL,
    [ObjectName] [sysname] NULL,
    [HostName] [sysname] NULL,
    [ProgramName] [sysname] NULL,
    [SqlCommand] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [XmlData] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [DDLTrigger_LogDDL]
    ON DATABASE
    FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE
        @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();

    INSERT INTO Meta.DdlEvents( 
        SqlCommand, 
        SchemaName,
        ObjectName,
        HostName,
        ProgramName,
        XmlData 
        ) 
    VALUES ( 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'), 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'),
        HOST_NAME(),
        PROGRAM_NAME(),
        @EventData 
        );
END
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [DDLTrigger_LogDDL] ON DATABASE
GO
```

Specifically, you use the `EVENTDATA()` function within the Database DDL trigger to get the Event XML, then you can extract the object(table's) object and schema at the `/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName` and `/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName` nodes.

---

Follow-up on Martin's comment below for the OP, a DDL triger only fires on DDL events, that is commands like `CREATE`,`ALTER` and `DROP`.  It does **not** fire for DML events like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.  So, if that is what you need, then this answer would not work, and yes, you would need a trigger on every table.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly they are asking if they can have a global DML trigger that fires on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE of any table

Comment: @MartinSmith AH.  Yes, this would not work for that.